# LINQ Query Optimization - joins

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this query and it's taking more than 20,000 ms to run!
I need to optimize it but I'm struggling a little with it.

```cs
var items = (
    from b in sourceBookingItemsQuery
    join ci in Context.ChargeableItemEntities on new { b.Id, OwnerId = ServerUser.PartyId.Value, ChargeTarget = criteria.Target.Value, IsDeleted = false }
        equals new { Id = ci.BookingItemId.Value, ci.OwnerId, ci.ChargeTarget, ci.IsDeleted } into chargeable
    from ci in chargeable.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where
        (criteria.Client == null || ci.ClientId == criteria.Client)
        && (criteria.IsLoaded == null || (criteria.IsLoaded.Value == (b.LoadingCode == "Y" || b.LoadingCode == "B")))
        && (criteria.LoadedFrom == null || b.ShippedOn >= criteria.LoadedFrom)
        && (criteria.LoadedTo == null || b.ShippedOn <= criteria.LoadedTo)
        && (criteria.BookedFrom == null || b.Booking.CreatedOn >= criteria.BookedFrom)
        && (criteria.BookedTo == null || b.Booking.CreatedOn <= criteria.BookedTo)
        && (criteria.SerialNumber == null || b.Parcel.SerialNumber == criteria.SerialNumber)
        && (!b.IsCanceled)
        && !(from y in Context.ChargeEntities
            where y.OwnerId == this.CurrentPartyId
            && y.Type.Target == criteria.Target
            && y.CounterpartRole == ChargeCounterpartRole.Client
            && (y.ItemType == InvoiceItemType.BookingService || y.ItemType == InvoiceItemType.ShippingUnit)
            && !y.IsDeleted
            && b.ParcelId == y.ParcelId
            && y.InvoiceId != null
            select y).Any()
    orderby b.Id descending
    select new BillableItemDetail()
    {
        Id = b.Id,
        OwnerId = b.OwnerId,
        Parcel = new ParcelReference() { Id = b.Parcel.Id, Description = b.Parcel.Description, SerialNumber = b.Parcel.SerialNumber },
        Pod = new PortReference() { Id = b.Pod.Id, Code = b.Pod.Code, Name = b.Pod.Description },
        Pol = new PortReference() { Id = b.Booking.PolId, Code = b.Booking.Pol.Code, Name = b.Booking.Pol.Description },
        Client = ci.Client != null ? new PartyReference() { Id = ci.ClientId.Value, Name = ci.Client.Name } : null,
        VoyageCode = b.Voyage != null ? b.Voyage.Code : null,
        ShippedOn = b.ShippedOn,
        Charges = (from y in Context.ChargeEntities
                where y.OwnerId == this.CurrentPartyId
                && y.Type.Target == criteria.Target
                && y.CounterpartRole == ChargeCounterpartRole.Client
                && (y.ItemType == InvoiceItemType.BookingService || y.ItemType == InvoiceItemType.ShippingUnit)
                && !y.IsDeleted
                && b.ParcelId == y.ParcelId
                && y.InvoiceId == null
                group y by y.Currency.Id into g
                select new BillableItemCharge()
                {
                    Amount = g.Sum(c => c.Amount),
                    Currency = new CurrencyEntry { Id = g.Key, Symbol = g.First().Currency.Symbol },
                    Target = g.First().Type.Target,
                    InvoiceId = g.First().InvoiceId,
                    ItemId = g.First().ItemId,
                }).ToArray()

    }) ;
```

I tried to change the join with ChargeableItems like this:

```cs
    from b in sourceBookingItemsQuery
    join ci in Context.ChargeableItemEntities on b.Id equals ci.BookingItemId.Value into chargeable
    from ci in chargeable.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where
    ci.OwnerId == ServerUser.PartyId.Value
    && ci.ChargeTarget== criteria.Target.Value
    && !ci.IsDeleted
```

The weird thing is that I got less rows than the first one.

Comment: Try comment out `Charges`, I think problem in this property initialization. Just to ensure.

Comment: So I get rid of a nested query with a join hmmm. But how would I get the needed data then

Comment: It is final result? You do not need pagination later? And tell me result of the commenting property. It is faster? Have you tried `AsSplitQuery()`?

Comment: We do not have enough information to give a direct answer but there is a process you can follow. If you can extract the queries into a [BenchmarkdotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) benchmark then you can try different versions of the query to get the performance you want. You can have a separate set of tests for the correctness of the queries. Looking at the query itself, I am assuming the problem is with the `y` subqueries which are executed for every row of `b`. That will seriously sap the performance. You will need to look at the plan generated by the DBMS to be sure.